# function that produces a list with range as parameter

Tags: python, function

why do the following lines of code:

```
def every_three_nums(start):
        lst = []
        for x in range(start,100,3):
                lst.append(x)
                return lst
```

when asking print(every_three_nums(91)) just returns 91 as output

thank you in advance for your support

Comment: Return lst should be indented left

Comment: You return inside the loop, which means the body of the loop just gets to be executed once. Unindent the `return`, and it will wait till the loop is done.

Comment: You return statement must be unindented. Return after the loop, not from the frist iteration

Comment: You are using `return` keyword. So, the for loop  just stops the first time

Comment: Why the loop? just use `return list(range(...))`

Comment: thank you all for the help and fast response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong indentation of return, so it will returen a list with just one element [91].
Actually you don't need that function, see below

```
def every_three_nums(start):
        lst = []
        for x in range(start,100,3):
                lst.append(x)
        return lst

print(every_three_nums(91))


print(list(range(91,100,3)))
```

The output is

```
[91, 94, 97]
[91, 94, 97]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your return is in the for, when a return is called the function ends, try this :

```
def every_three_nums(start):
        lst = []
        for x in range(start,100,3):
            lst.append(x)
        return lst
```